# Adding Swift file to my project causes invalid module error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In XCode 8.3 I have an Objective-C project. I'm trying to add a single Swift file to this project but when I add the file I get an error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: module name "" is not a valid identifier
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

Literally all I do is add a Swift file and I get this error, I change nothing else. It runs without the Swift file without any errors but as soon as I add it I get this. I am new to Swift but I try to figure things out on my own before I bother anyone with a question here but I just can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're retrofitting Swift, please check:
`SWIFT_MODULE_NAME` under build settings in the target (and additionally at the project level perhaps if you have more targets).

It should be SOMETHING (versus blank), usually ${BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME} but you can hard-code it for starters.

There may be other settings like default module name for XIB also.

Comment: For some reason my Product Module Name was empty so I made it ${BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME}. Afterwards I get <unknown>:0: error: bridging header '/Users/thailey/XCode Projects/Wise Guys/Wise Guys/Wise Guys-Bridging-Header.h' does not exist

Comment: So I manually add the Bridging Header and I get <unknown>:0: error: module name "com.trevcor.Wise-Guys" is not a valid identifier
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Comment: Ok I just changed the Product Module Name to my project name without spaces or extra characters, for some reason that mattered. It is working now, thank you for the hint!

Comment: Glad to hear, it needs to follow the same rules as variable naming

Answer (score 0):

In my case, an empty PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME was the culprit.

I opened the project.pbxproj file in an editor and scrolled down to the section labeled /* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */

I then simply deleted the following line for each of my app's build configs, and was able to build:

```
PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME = "";
```